# curl_easy_perform() libcurl function not returning html from website

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Trying to simply get the html data from a website using libcurl library but curl_easy_perform() is not returning the data. I am using the same code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uha3JGPRIQs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;                           // Handle to a transfer
  CURLcode res;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);    // initialization
  
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl)
  {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        cout << "ERROR";
        
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

This code outputs "ERROR" from this line: if (res != CURLE_OK). If anyone can help me understand why it is doing this I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: What is the actual value of `res`? That will tell you WHY `curl_easy_perform()` is failing. Have you [read the documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html) yet? "*`CURLE_OK` (0) means everything was ok, **non-zero means an error occurred** as `<curl/curl.h>` defines - see [libcurl-errors](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html). If the `CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER` was set with `curl_easy_setopt` there will be a readable error message in the error buffer when non-zero is returned.*"

Comment: Things that often makes it fail is that sites redirect pages to other pages and in that case you need `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. In some cases you may be behind a proxy and in that case you may also need `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL`. You could also make the output a bit more verbose to let you follow what it's doing by setting `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you, I guess a lot of sites don't work with this program. The problem with this is that example.com URL does not have https in it, so I got rid of that and it works now.

Comment: @PatrickAliberti Oh, great :-)